# How to detect a new line and add it to the string. Fstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hello I created this program and the only problem is I don't know how to detect a new line and how to add \n to the string every time new line occurs. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 if it matters. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream ofile;
    ifstream ifile;

    string filehold;
    vector<string> data;

    string line;

    ofile.open("C:/Users/Nada/Desktop/data.txt");

    ofile << "ph4n70m is awesome \n LOL im awesome"<< flush;

    ifile.open("C:/Users/Nada/Desktop/data.txt");

    if (ifile.fail()) {
        cerr << "Error!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!ifile.eof()) {
        ifile >> filehold;
        data.push_back(filehold);
    }

    cout << "data.txt: " << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        cout << data[i] + " ";
    }

    ifile.close();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline()` instead of reading single words. Newline can't be detected that way, it is considered a whitespace and skipped.

Comment: You can use `std::istream::getline`.

Comment: But where do i put it?

Comment: @TechnologyExposed Here: `while (!ifile.eof()) {` instead of the `!ifile.eof()`.

Comment: I get the output data.txt: 
LOL
LOL

Answer (score 0):

Change your reading loop to

```
while (std::getline(ifile,filehold)) {
    filehold += '\n';
    data.push_back(filehold);
}
```